# Calculating the number of username possibilities

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a 6-character username that consists of three lower case letters, then three numbers, how would I find the number of usernames that do not end in 111?

I tried doing something like $26×26×26×10×9×8$ to see the what the username possibilities are where the same 3 numbers aren't being used, but I'm not sure how to go from there and be specific with finding the username possibilities that don't end with the same specific number in a row.

Comment: I suggest to calculate all cases and minus from the case that end to 111.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since characters can repeat (no restriction was imposed on them):

*Letters*: $26×26×26=17576$ possibilities
*Numbers*: $10×10×10$ combinations, but subtract 1 since the 111 ending is not allowed, thus 999 possibilities
*Multiply*: $17576×999=17558424$ possible usernames.

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't really think it was going to be that simple. Looks like I overcomplicated it.

Comment: @user411697 Please accept my answer (by clicking on the green tick below the up/down buttons to the left of my answer).

Comment: Done. Thanks again!